# Call listener when calendar date changes, but ignore time change

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces, calendar, onchange

I have a calendar declared in this way (calendar with a slider to change hour)

```
<p:calendar id="date" value="#{model.date}"
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:00" mask="true" navigator="true">
    <f:converter converterId="multiDateConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern1" value="dd/MM/yyyy HH:00" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern2" value="ddMMyyyy HH:00" />
    <p:ajax event="change"
        listener="#{service.onChangeDate}" process="@form"
        update="mainForm, :msgDialog" />
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
        listener="#{service.onChangeDate}" process="@form"
        update="mainForm, :msgDialog" />
</p:calendar>
```

I would like to call the listener "onChangeDate" only when a date is selected, meaning that I don't want to fire the event when I change only the hour of the day. Is there a way to achieve this? The "dateSelect" event fires when something is changed, being the day or the hour, but I would like it to be called only when selecting a day.

Comment: You may have to do this by hand. When you set up your form, store the date in a field called "lastDate" or something. When the listener is fired, you should get the current value and compare it to "lastDate". If the day, month and year are the same, do not proceed. After, set lastDate to the current one

Comment: I thought about it, but the calendar disappears once I click on something...

Comment: TIps: The troublesome class `Calendar` is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Use `LocalDate` and `ZoneId` instead. And serialize date-time values to text using standard ISO 8601 formats instead of defining your own. The java.classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.